# error using ucanaccess in osgi

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, ucanaccess

I have read the question [UcanAccess intro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc) but can not get the driver to work in an OSGi / RCP application. I think it is a classloader issue but don't know how to resolve it.

Relevant snippet of code, it fails on the second line.  The MDB exists and a non-OSGi Java app using the UcanAccess can successfully open it.

```
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + FILENAME);
```

I get the following exception:

```
**4302 INFO  org.eclipse.ecf.osgi.services.remoteserviceadmin - [S:{org.osgi.framework.hooks.service.EventListenerHook}={service.id=274, service.bundleid=86, service.scope=singleton}] ServiceEvent REGISTERED
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: user lacks privilege or object not found java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.ucanaccess.converters.Functions cannot be found by org.hsqldb.hsqldb_2.3.1 net.ucanaccess.converters.Functions in statement [CREATE FUNCTION SLN(par0 DOUBLE,par1 DOUBLE,par2 DOUBLE) RETURNS DOUBLE  LANGUAGE JAVA DETERMINISTIC NO SQL  EXTERNAL NAME 'CLASSPATH:net.ucanaccess.converters.Functions.sln']
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:247)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at com.easa.motordb.load.HornerLoad.execute(HornerLoad.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:701)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$6(HandledContributionItem.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at com.easa.acmotor.base.Application.start(Application.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.ucanaccess.converters.Functions cannot be found by org.hsqldb.hsqldb_2.3.1 net.ucanaccess.converters.Functions in statement [CREATE FUNCTION SLN(par0 DOUBLE,par1 DOUBLE,par2 DOUBLE) RETURNS DOUBLE  LANGUAGE JAVA DETERMINISTIC NO SQL  EXTERNAL NAME 'CLASSPATH:net.ucanaccess.converters.Functions.sln']
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet.exec(LoadJet.java:1258)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet.access$0(LoadJet.java:1253)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$FunctionsLoader.createFunctions(LoadJet.java:156)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$FunctionsLoader.addFunctions(LoadJet.java:151)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$FunctionsLoader.loadMappedFunctions(LoadJet.java:178)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$FunctionsLoader.access$2(LoadJet.java:177)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet.loadDB(LoadJet.java:1310)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:236)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.ucanaccess.converters.Functions cannot be found by org.hsqldb.hsqldb_2.3.1 net.ucanaccess.converters.Functions
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Routine.getMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Routine.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Routine.resolveReferences(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Routine.resolve(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.ucanaccess.converters.Functions cannot be found by org.hsqldb.hsqldb_2.3.1
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    ... 67 more
```

Steps I have taken:

1. Create a plugin/bundle from ucanaccess
2. Require-Bundle: org.hsqldb.hsqldb;bundle-version="2.3.1" in the Manifest
3. Make it a registered buddy (Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: registered)
4. Make my bundle know about it (Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: ucanaccess)
5. Ensure all bundles are autostarted (ucanaccess, hsql and my bundle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally included only the ucanaccess.jar file in the new bundle and put the other jar files in the target platform / plugin list.

The solution was to create the new bundle with ALL UcanAccess required jar files (ucanaccess-2.0.9.4.jar, commons-lang-2.6.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, hsqldb.jar, jackcess-2.0.8.jar).

Answer (score 0):

You have neglected to place empty ""s for the database username and password in your getConnection. Try this code:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + FILENAME, "", "");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but same error with con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + FILENAME, "", "");

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably solved by now, but for those who can do with another tip: Drop the line.

```
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
```

It worked wonderfully for me. I use JDK 1.8 and Jackcess 2.08
Yrs Truly